# Building playframework projects leads to this error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

Error: Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.

Comment: Your question is to broad, add sample code what have you try (Ebean config, sample model) otherwise it will be closed without any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ebean moved to being an external dependency in Play 2.4.  You can read about it in the [migration guide](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Ebean-dependency):

> Ebean has been pulled out into an external project, to allow it to have a lifecycle independent of Play’s own lifecycle. The Ebean bytecode enhancement functionality has also been extracted out of the Play sbt plugin into its own plugin.
>
> To migrate an existing Play project that uses Ebean to use the new external Ebean plugin, remove javaEbean from your libraryDependencies in `build.sbt`, and add the following to `project/plugins.sbt`:
>
> `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")`
>
> After that, enable Ebean plugin for your project:
>
> `lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
>     .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)`
>
> And finally, configure Ebean mapped classes as a list instead of a comma separated string (which is still supported but was deprecated):
>
> `ebean.default = ["models.*"]`
>
> `ebean.orders = ["models.Order", "models.OrderItem"]`
>
> Additionally, Ebean has been upgraded to 4.5.x, which pulls in a few of the features that Play previously added itself, including the `Model` class. Consequently, the Play Model class has been deprecated, in favour of using `com.avaje.ebean.Model`.

Comment: thanks i got the out put.i have added all the above things in build.sbt....@Steve chaloner